# I2C/SPI interview questions

Tags: linux, serial-port, signal-processing, i2c, spi

1. Can devices be added and removed while the system is running (Hot swapping) in I2C and SPI ?
2. Is it better to use I2C or SPI for data communication between a microprocessor and DSP ?
3. Is it better to use I2C or SPI for data communication from ADC ?

Comment: In the title, did you mean `interface` vice `interview`?

Comment: I just noticed this was on SO. Wouldn't this fit better on EE?

Comment: Maybe start with some wiki info for [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Limitations) and [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Pros_and_cons_of_SPI) and then more narrowly define your design/performance/testing requirements.

Answer (score 4):

1) Of course, given no limitations.

SPI would be easiest, as each device would have an independent chip select. You'd just have to make sure that the SPI device didn't think its chip select was active at some point during the connect/disconnect process or it might assert its MISO line and cause contention. There would be many ways to sequence the power or reset of that SPI device to ensure that part worked.

I2C would be trickier... as a device connecting during a transfer might interpret the first bytes it sees in the ongoing transfer as a command and potentially do bad things. You could put a bidirectional level shifter or buffer with an enable and perhaps a flop to latch the enable in front of the hot swapped I2C device, and strobe a secondary "bus_clear" message to enable any new hot swapped buffers during these at idle periods on the bus. There'd be lots of ways to accomplish the same thing.

2) and 3) have no general answer.

SPI would be capable of going faster, so if you need speed that'd be the way to go. The micro to DSP implies that. However, just the fact that one is a micro and the other is a DSP doesn't tell you anything at all unless you start assuming things. What if the micro is just getting small result packets from a whole set of DSPs? I2C would make that easier.

Similarly, ADCs *might* need speed, or they might not. If there are a lot of them and the required data rate is low, again I2C makes more sense.

SPI is almost always simpler to use, so that's a plus if there's not too many devices. I2C uses fewer pins.

Many times, the choice between I2C or SPI is made based on what the parts you want to use are providing as the interface. Another very important factor is what ELSE needs to happen in the system and what bus makes sense for as much of the parts as possible.

There's more: design reuse, weird firmware/RTOS limitations, etc, etc. There are many reasons you can't say one is "better" than the other in general.  What's better for your design is just not that simple.

I think these questions are "get you talking" questions...